# how can i store multiple data in sharedpreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

I am getting user information like the username , profile pic and name .I want to store all that info inside `Sharedpreferences` so that i wont have to call firebase every time I need them.
here is how i am getting the data ,how can i store this data so that later on i can get user's name and its profilepic by checking it through its username ?

```
storeUsersInfo()async{
    print('STORE CALLED');
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await DatabaseMethods().getUsers();
    var length = querySnapshot.docs.length ;
      print(length);
      int i = 0 ;
    while (  i < length ) {
      print(name = "${querySnapshot.docs[i]["name"]}");
      print(profilePicUrl = "${querySnapshot.docs[i]["profileURL"]}");
      i++;

    }
  }
```

here is the firebase call

```
 Future<QuerySnapshot> getUsers() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .get();
  }
```

and if anyone needs anything else please ask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the information in SharePreference by encoding picture objects to Base64String before storing them.

**How you can encode it:**

```
Future<String> encodeImageToBase64String(String imageUrl) async {
  
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
 
  final base64 = base64Encode(response.bodyBytes);

  return base64;
}
```

After Encoding the image, you can **cache it to sharedPreference** using

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

//Save string to SharedPreference
pref.setString('image', encodedImageString);
```

**How to Decode and use Image Later**

```
//Get Encoded Image String from SharedPreferences
final base64String = pref.getString('image');

///Decodes Images file encoded to Base64String to Image
Uint8List decodeImageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
  return base64Decode(base64String);
}
```

Finally, you can use this in your `Image` Widget like so

```
...
Image(image: MemoryImage(decodeImageFromBase64String))
```

**Assuming you want to cache name, username and image gotten from firebase**

```
//Create a model for the firebase data
class UserModel{
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String encodedImage;
  
  UserModel(this.name, this.username, this.encodedImage);
  
  String toJson(){
    Map<String, dynamic> userMap = {
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'image': encodedImage,
    };
    
    return json.encode(userMap);
  }
}
```

```
//Encode the image HERE
encodeImageToBase64String(imageUrl);
 
//Pass in the parameters to the UserModel() constructor and Call //the toJson(), then Cache the Resulting String
String stringToCache = UserModel(nameString, usernameString, encodedImageString).toJson();
```

Comment: ok . so the issue is i am receiving a stream of the last message and the user name , so how can i store it like , suppose you messaged me and i have your username ,and all your info in the firebase , so i want assign those to your last message .so can i store it it like with username , name and profile so i can show them with your last message ?

Comment: Let me get it clearly. You want to update an information already in SharedPreferences, right? Let me also assume you need to store the  gotten data as a single Object and not the image object only

Comment: yes , i am trying an alternative for this problem(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422121/receiving-data-from-stream-but-function-is-not-working) because am not able to find any solution.

Comment: I just added more details to help with your problem. This stores all the data as an object. I have implemented this and it works

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences takes a key and the data.
use this in an async funtion.
This syntax is `sharedPreferences.setString(key, value)`
So in a function,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['access_token'].toString());
sharedPreferences.setString("userId", jsonResponse['customer_id'].toString());
```

You can get the stored data by `sharedPreferences.getString(key)`.Like

```
var token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
```

Comment: what I am trying to do is this . (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422121/receiving-data-from-stream-but-function-is-not-working) .but not able to achieve anything . i also tried to call  the `getUserInfo`  by stream listen but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cache like https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_cache which does that for you.